# Is it legal to create an app that stores a user's ID cards (on-device only), do I need to comply with any laws?

Tags: internet, identification

I'm (individual, not business) planning on starting work on an iOS app that will launch on the App Store that allows users to store their ID information on their device - including a photo of their card, and text of their information.

This information will always be stored on-device, and will never be uploaded to the internet or viewed by a third-party. It won't even be uploaded to iCloud either, and there's no sharing or backup option. All it does with the data is allow you to register it, view it, and delete it.

It will be stored in Core Data without any extra processing or security added to it than what's added by default in the OS.

Is this app going to be legal? Am I opening myself up to legal trouble?

Thanks!

Comment: With my current phone, I am already capable of storing arbitrary text and a photo (of my ID or anything else) ...

Comment: This will depend entirely on jurisdiction, and for what purpose your app uses this information. For example in the EU, countries are likely to have laws that regulate how government ID cards can be used, in particular the ID number on the card.

Comment: Do these varying laws open me up to legal trouble? Will I have to research every country and only launch the app to those specific regions?